# DataTrigger not working on CheckBox

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I have the following DataTrigger in a WPF form:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ConcentratorViewModel.Integrated}">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>-->
            <!--<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>-->

             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConcentratorViewModel.Manufacturer}" Value="ZIV">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                     <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                 </DataTrigger>

                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConcentratorViewModel.Manufacturer}" Value="Landis+Gyr">
                     <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>                                    
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

The CheckBox must be Checked or Unchecked depending on the selected manufacturer. I added a converter to see the value on the trigger and it's correct. I've also added the Background property and it changes correctly, but the IsChecked doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you need to move the `IsChecked` Binding inside the `Style`. Setting it directly on the `Checkbox` gives it precedence and the Trigger's cannot change that value.

So something like:

```
<CheckBox>
  <CheckBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
      <Setter Property="Margin"
              Value="0,10,0,0" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="20" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
              Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="IsChecked"
              Value="{Binding ConcentratorViewModel.Integrated}" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConcentratorViewModel.Manufacturer}"
                     Value="ZIV">
          <Setter Property="Background"
                  Value="Red" />
          <Setter Property="IsChecked"
                  Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConcentratorViewModel.Manufacturer}"
                     Value="Landis+Gyr">
          <Setter Property="IsChecked"
                  Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

**Note:**

Remember by doing this, your `Binding` only applies when the `DataTrigger`'s do not evaluate to "True". Thus if your `Manufacturer` property is "ZIV" or "Landis+Gyr" then your `Integrated` property is not going to see any CheckBox updates even with a `TwoWay` binding as it just isn't being used.

Comment: Thanks!! It works perfectly now.
At first I didn't understand your note, but now I see that if I change the checkbox manually (by checking/unchecking), the binding with the property doesn't work.
Anyway I'm using the checkbox in "read only mode". User won't be able to check it. It will only change when the manufacturer (a ComboBox) is changed. So binding should work as expected isn't it?

Comment: OK...binding doesn't work now. The answer is correct, but I've to find other solution.

Comment: Yeh we need to rephrase `{Binding ConcentratorViewModel.Integrated}` "working" to "being used". The binding always works. it just isn't used if the `DataTrigger` set's the `CheckBox` value itself.

Comment: @pete for your current problem, what you can try is when Manufacturer is "Landis+Gyr" or "ZIV", inside the `DataTrigger` set the `CheckBox` to ReadOnly(don't set the `IsChecked` value). Just set the `Integrated` property in your VM / code-behind file to True or False based on manufacturer. This way the binding is always active for `IsChecked`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now. Sometimes we put too much effort to do all in XAML and keep VM/code-behind clear ;). Thanks again!

Comment: @pete With MVVM this would be a "should be tested feature"(check if `Integrated` is True if manufacturer is "ZIV"...) making it not a concern of the View. Thus "do all in xaml" shouldn't even be applied for MVVM users here